# getting dynamically content height of iframe by javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

first i did my research on this topic after reading and applying so many JS i posting this problem,

i am trying to apply iframe in which i get content from some other domain.

i m trying to set the iframe height on the base of scrollheight of the content inside the iframe but failed to do so

i tried to use onload event of iframe but failed...

please help me i need to set the height of iframe dynamically by any mean necessary ..

if the code would be provided in Javascript that would be helpful to me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, it is not possible to interact with a frame in a different domain.

That includes measuring its content.

Comment: can we find specific element in the iframe content ?? by javascript and get its height ..... ??

Comment: **No.  For security reasons, it is not possible to interact with a frame in a different domain.

That includes measuring _part of_ its content.**

Comment: then only possible way that i could think that is i bring other domain page on my domain and then do working on it .....

Comment: @NewbieFreak: SLaks is right. However there still is a way to make the iframe send you it's new height. Read my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

@SLaks is correct. If the iframe content is on a different domain you cannot access its contents directly.

What you could do (and what I recently just did) is setup a proxy that pulls the content in via cURL (in php but im sure whatever server side language has something that is the equivalent). The iframe content is then on the same page and you can access the height of it via:

```
var _iframeHeight = $('#iframe').contents().find('body').height();
$('#iframe').height(_iframeHeight);
```

Also I forgot to mention (@SLaks thanks for the reminder) You would have to check all the script/style/image tags and check/add an absolute url to it. The proxy can get pretty tricky but it will get it done.

Comment: However, this will break scripts and images unless done very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to alter the content inside the iframe, for example if you are the author or can contact the author of that iframe content, you can setup a double-iframe trick to send the height of the iframe to your main page.

Here is how that can be accomplished:

1. In your main page (`AAA.com/mainpage.htm`) you put an iframe (`BBB.com/mainframe.htm`).
2. Together with your main page, you create another page (`AAA.com/heightproxy.htm`)
3. You make that `BBB.com/mainframe.htm` would create an invisible iframe with `AAA.com/heightproxy.htm` inside.

   **Result:** `BBB.com/mainframe.htm` on it's onload event can load it's iframe `AAA.com/heightproxy.htm` with some parameters added to URL. For example, it can put it's new height/width there into the parameters. Also, `AAA.com/heightproxy.htm` can access all JS function in `AAA.com/mainpage.htm` - as they are in same browser window and share same domain. This way it can redirect the width and height it received to the mainpage.

Disclaimer: This trick is only possible if you can modify the source of the iframe you need to include.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact main page from iFrame if content is loaded from different URL (you can measure height from iframe, but cannot pass it to main page). 
That can be overridden by loading content via simple proxy script.

Comment: `<iframe>` is not an Apple product.

Comment: Apple did not invented Latin letters to owe the sequences ;)

Comment: And therefore it should not be capitalized like an Apple product.